# "there is insufficient memory on the device"

Tags: google-play-store, internal-storage, insufficient-memory, google, android-versions

Well my dad just bought some phone for me "x-touch ocean" and I've beeeeeen trying to download apps but it keeps saying "insufficient memory on the device" I tried deleting apps I already found in the phone but still.. I got a new memory card with nothing in it but it still says the same thing over and over.. I haven't downloaded anything at all by the way. And I tried to move apps to the memory card but none of them can be moved unfortunately. Please some one help  #frustrated 15 year old #

Comment: Additionally to being a duplicate: I've just added the `insufficient-memory` tag to your question. You might wish to check [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for some background (which also includes some first-aid).

Answer (score 0):

Google 1tap cleaner free then download and install it. Clear cache using that app. Then try to download any all from play store again.

Comment: Do you have a link to the app you're talking about?